# Android fading a layout

Tags: android, layout, view, alpha, fading

I'm having a view initially invisible, I want a fading effect when changing it's visibility, I wrote this code, but the layout does not appear at all.Neither  OnAnimationStart nor OnAnimationEnd are executed.However run() is executed

Here's my code:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("run","run");
            Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in_view);
            layout.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);

            fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    Log.i("onAnimationStart","onAnimationStart");
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Log.i("onAnimationEnd","onAnimationEnd");
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `loadAnimation` use this code and try

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,android.R.anim.fade_out);
  target.startAnimation(animation);
```